A very simple screen capture and stream on Win64+ffmpeg
I need to stream my desktop to a TV, what I need is soo simple and I'm getting crazy to find a solution trying and failing with everything, please help me.
VLC and udp streaming, works very bad, please let's move over it.
Go2RTC producing HLS stream works good, but I can't find any way to capture screen with that, the internal feature doesn't work, and I can't argument ffmpeg there to capture stream exec:ffmpeg.exe: -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop, while the DOS command line ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="screen-capture-recorder" output.mkv works good.
Then I've tried to output with OBS a kind of stream and import then to Go2RTC, but OBS pretends to connect to a server and I don't know how to open a server with Go2RTC. Looks crazy.
The only solution for now is to use RTSP plugin on OBS, then connect to it with Go2RTC and produce HLS, but the results are poor, low frame rate, etc.
